# There is no Github pages section in repository settings

Tags: ruby, github, repository, jekyll, github-pages

as the title says, when i go to repository settings and scroll down i don't see the Github Pages section. Did i do something wrong ?

I was watching [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EX4w9hsduNA) video because i wanted to add a custom domain to my github pages website
but there isn't a section for that for me when i go to repository settings. You can see it on the video at 0:49

I have tried making a new repository with that ends with github.io /example name.github.io but to no avail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follow such URL

```
https://github.com/<user>/<repo>/settings/pages
```

Or go to repo settings and choose in tab `Code and automation` item `Pages`

[image]